# How to stop follow command on journalctl log file without ctrl+c and save the output to a file

Tags: command-line, bash, systemd-journald

I am running the following command and saving the output to a file:

```
sudo journalctl -u iotedge -f >> sub.txt
```

the problem is ,i have to stop the operation of the command with ctrl+c otherwise it won't go back to command prompt. Is there any way to stop the follow command and save it's output to a file without pressing ctrl+c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man journactl`:

> -f, --follow
>
> Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new
>              entries as they are appended to the journal.

So just remove the `-f` from the command.